Using ucharclasses and babel together
How can I use ucharclasses with babel in XeLaTeX while defining the font with \babelfont? Alternatively, is there a method to achieve automatic locale and font switching in XeLaTeX, rather than LuaLaTeX, without relying on ucharclasses? I prefer not to replace babel with polyglossia, and I've seen this method on Stack Exchange before. Here's a minimal working example of my attempt.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[CJK,Cyrillics,Latin]{ucharclasses}

\babelprovide[import]{chinese}
\babelprovide[import,main]{english}
\babelprovide[import]{french}
\babelprovide[import]{russian}

\babelfont{rm}[
    Extension       = .otf,
    BoldFont        = NewCM10-Bold,
    ItalicFont      = NewCM10-BookItalic,
    BoldItalicFont  = NewCM10-BoldItalic
]{NewCM10-Book}
\babelfont{sf}[
    Extension       = .otf,
    BoldFont        = NewCMSans10-Bold,
    ItalicFont      = NewCMSans10-BookOblique,
    BoldItalicFont  = NewCMSans10-BoldOblique
]{NewCMSans10-Book}
\babelfont{tt}[
    Extension       = .otf,
    BoldFont        = NewCMMono10-Bold,
    ItalicFont      = NewCMMono10-BookItalic,
    BoldItalicFont  = NewCMMono10-BoldOblique
]{NewCMMono10-Book}
\babelfont[chinese]{rm}[
    Extension       = .otf,
    BoldFont        = FandolSong-Bold,
    ItalicFont      = FandolKai-Regular
]{FandolSong-Regular}
\babelfont[chinese]{sf}[
    Extension       = .otf,
    BoldFont        = FandolHei-Bold
]{FandolHei-Regular}
\babelfont[chinese]{tt}[
    Extension       = .otf
]{FandolFang-Regular}

\begin{document}

This is English.

这是中文。

Это русский.

\end{document}

I'd appreciate any insights on how to get ucharclasses to work with babel in XeLaTeX, or suggestions for alternative approaches to achieving automatic font and locale switching. Thanks in advance!

You must define the transitions. An option is:
\setTransitionsForCyrillics{\selectlanguage{russian}}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\setTransitionsForChinese{\selectlanguage{chinese}}{\selectlanguage{english}}

However, ucharclasses doesn’t include the Chinese period in the Chinese text.

Thank you very much. But could you please explain why the individual Chinese periods are printed correctly?

No idea, to be honest. Either it’s a limitation of ucharclasses or it’s a limitation of mine.

Wouldn't \begin{otherlanguage*} and \end{otherlanguage*} be better?

I don’t like opening a group and trusting it’s closed. It’s a matter of personal taste, I’d say.

Using the command \selectlanguage or the environment otherlanguage* are good approaches, but the following method seems to work better. For example, consider 你好，\languagename\languagename.
\newif\iflang@save
\newif\iflang@set

\setTransitionsForCJK{%
    \iflang@save
        \iflang@set
            \edef\langname{\languagename}%
        \fi
    \else
        \edef\langname{\languagename}%
    \fi
    \selectlanguage{chinese}\lang@savetrue\lang@setfalse%
}{%
    \edef\selectlang{\noexpand\selectlanguage{\langname}}\selectlang\lang@savefalse\lang@settrue%
}

